# Using a variable to call a nested workflow

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have several smaller workflow that I need to call and I have in my parent workflow a variable that represents the name of the workflow.

Is it possible to somehow create an action to call a nested workflow but use the incoming variable as the name of the workflow?

Thanks!

larry

Answer (score 2):

The [Workflow Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#workflow-action) requires the resource id of the workflow as a string and doesn't accept variables.

Instead, you can achieve calling workflows dynamically as follow

1. Get the Workflow URI via [ARM Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/arm/#invoke-resource-operation) by calling the [`Workflow Triggers - List Callback Url` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowtriggers/listcallbackurl)

   [image: arm-action-get-workflow-url]
2. Use the `value` property returned in an [HTTP Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http)

   [image: call-workflow-using-http-action]